# Get tuple and list linked as result

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have this query :

```
var query = (from tables ... 
             where ...
             select new
             {
                 ClientName = ClientName,
                 ClientNumber = ClientNumber,
                 ClientProduct = ClientProduct
             }).Distinct();
```

which returns rows with 3 values. 
ClientName and ClientNumber can be linked to multiple products.

So we can have :

```
NameA NumberA Product1
NameA NumberA Product2
NameA NumberA Product3
NameB NumberB Product4
NameC NumberC Product5
```

I would like to know if it is possible to store that in a List of a certain class which would be like :

```
class MyClass
{
    string ClientName, 
    int ClientNumber, 
    List<int> ClientProducts
}
```

So there are no duplicate of ClientName and ClientNumber.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this class structure to represent your data:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public int ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public List<int> ClientProducts { get; set; }
}

class Procuct
{
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public int ClientNumber { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
}
```

and this test data:

```
List<Procuct> Products = new List<Procuct>()
{
    new Procuct() { ClientName = "A", ClientNumber = 1, ProductID = 1},
    new Procuct() { ClientName = "A", ClientNumber = 1, ProductID = 2},
    new Procuct() { ClientName = "A", ClientNumber = 1, ProductID = 3},
    new Procuct() { ClientName = "B", ClientNumber = 2, ProductID = 4},
    new Procuct() { ClientName = "C", ClientNumber = 2, ProductID = 5}
};
```

you can use the following linq query:

```
var q = from p in Products
        group p by new 
        {
           cName = p.ClientName,
           cNumber = p.ClientNumber
        } into pGroup
        select new MyClass
        {
           ClientName = pGroup.Key.cName,
           ClientNumber = pGroup.Key.cNumber,
           ClientProducts = pGroup.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList()
        };
```

to get exactly what you want, i.e. a collection of `MyClass` objects.

The ***Grouping*** performed in the above linq query essentially guarantees that there will be no duplicates on `(ClientName, ClientNumber)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Linq-to-sql, most probably you Client entity already has the products linked. You might look for an overcomplicated solution.

It depends a bit on your foreign key stucture, but if your datamodel would be
Client has 1-many product and you have a Foreign key from product to client it is already present.

So you can just reference `client.Products`.

So in your case it would be

```
var query = (from Clients... 
             where ...
             select new
             {
                 ClientName = Client.ClientName,
                 ClientNumber = Client.ClientNumber,
                 ClientProduct = Client.Products.Select(s=>s.id).ToList()
             });
```

But you might as well simply use your client entity with a eager load of the products.

*It all depends on your datamodel + proper foreign key structure*
if you have a many-many associations like Product-per-client between your client and product you can start from that entity. Have a look at this documentation - it provides a good starting point for Linq-2-sql.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-linq-to-sql-part-1

Answer (score 0):

I solve same problem , I think it useful to you
Only check your **Where** Condition properly
Thank...

```
var query = (from tables ... 
         where ...
         select new
         {
             ClientName = ClientName,
             ClientNumber = ClientNumber,
             ClientProduct = ClientProduct.ToList()
         }).Distinct();
```